# Get the logs per player while using one LibVLC object

Tags: libvlcsharp

I want to know if there is a way to distinguish between logs that come from different media players initialized from the same `LibVLC()` object.

I am trying to achieve the same thing as the user from this post: 
[libvlcsharp : Get the logs per player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754077/libvlcsharp-get-the-logs-per-player/57755502#57755502)

This issue doesn't provide a solution. It just says it was fixed in 3.2.2 but doesn't mention how to implement it. And, it was over 4 years ago so, I wanted to create a new post.

Please let me know if there is a way to get this working. Thanks in advance.